# phppgAdmin has more than 1 Error - also Error Loading servers.php

Tags: php, phppgadmin, php-pgsql

I am trying to learn PostgreSQL and so installed it and phppgAdmin on my laptop.

I went to localhost/phppgadmin, logged in and I get all these errors on the front page:

I tried going troubleshooting on Google, but unfortunately there are not enough answers to this question.

[image: Shown Errors]

Also, config.inc.php file looks like this after I altered it according to the Tutorial I followed to connect the Database to PHP:

```
$conf['servers'][0]['desc'] = 'PostgreSQL';

// Hostname or IP address for server.  Use '' for UNIX domain socket.
// use 'localhost' for TCP/IP connection on this computer
$conf['servers'][0]['host'] = 'localhost';

// Database port on server (5432 is the PostgreSQL default)
$conf['servers'][0]['port'] = 5432;

// Database SSL mode
// Possible options: disable, allow, prefer, require
// To require SSL on older servers use option: legacy
// To ignore the SSL mode, use option: unspecified
$conf['servers'][0]['sslmode'] = 'allow';

// Change the default database only if you cannot connect to template1.
// For a PostgreSQL 8.1+ server, you can set this to 'postgres'.
$conf['servers'][0]['defaultdb'] = 'template1';

// Specify the path to the database dump utilities for this server.
// You can set these to '' if no dumper is available.
$conf['servers'][0]['pg_dump_path'] = '/usr/bin/pg_dump';
$conf['servers'][0]['pg_dumpall_path'] = 'C:\\xampp\\pgSql\\11.2\\pg_dumpall.exe';
```

Thank you in advance

EDIT: Is it possible to just user the original pgadmin?!

Comment: Smells like pretty old version?

Comment: You need to provide the phpPgAdmin version, as Marcin said it appears outdated.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski this is the phppgadmin version - v 1.55 2008/02/18 21:10:31 found on top of the config.inc.php file

Comment: Well the latest version is 5.6 and based on your comment it is over 10 years old.

Comment: I downloaded the 5.6 version a couple minutes ago and apparently it's only written wrong at the top of the config.inc.php file, is it possible to just use pgadmin instead?!

Comment: I don't know much about postgre, but yeah you should be fine using that instead for administration.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the version of phpPgAdmin you are running does not support php7. You can either downgrade your PHP version or run the code from git master, available at https://github.com/phppgadmin/phppgadmin.